# X&0 Game IPC FIFO windows

Tags: c++

i want to make a x&0 game with ipc in c.i declare 3 char arrays,read the witch line to choose and the on what position to put the x or 0.when i try to send line number through the fifo from the client the server recieves a different number.for example i send 1 and the server gets  3144200....this is the code it's not all just one read and write.
this is the server:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
HANDLE f1, f2;
DWORD x;
char l1[3]="\0";
char l2[3]="\0";
char l3[3]="\0";
char X='x';
char* a="";
char* lineChar="";
int n=1,lineInt=0,coor=0;
printf("I am the server \n");
printf("You will play with x\n");
// creating pipes
f1=CreateNamedPipe(TEXT("\\\\.\\PIPE\\fifo1"), PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND,PIPE_TYPE_BYTE|PIPE_WAIT, 3, 0, 0, 0, NULL);
f2=CreateNamedPipe(TEXT("\\\\.\\PIPE\\fifo2"), PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND,PIPE_TYPE_BYTE|PIPE_WAIT, 3, 0, 0, 0, NULL);
ConnectNamedPipe(f1, NULL);
ConnectNamedPipe(f2, NULL);

while(n<=9){
    for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){
        printf("[%s]",&l1[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){
        printf("[%s]",&l2[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){
        printf("[%s]",&l3[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("You will begin,select the line from 1 to 3 : \n");
    scanf_s("%d",&lineInt);
    x=0;
    lineChar=reinterpret_cast<char*>(lineInt);
    printf("%s",lineChar);
    //strcpy_s(a,sizeof(lineChar),lineChar);
    if (WriteFile(f2,lineChar,sizeof(lineChar)+1, &x, NULL)==0) {
                printf("writing error..%d\n", x);
    }
    n++;
}
DisconnectNamedPipe(f1);
DisconnectNamedPipe(f2);
CloseHandle(f1);
CloseHandle(f2);
}
```

this is the client :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
HANDLE f1, f2;
DWORD x;
char l1[3]="\0";
char l2[3]="\0";
char l3[3]="\0";
char o='0';
char* lineChar="";
int n=1,lineInt=0,coor=0;
printf("I am the client \n");
printf("You will play with 0\n");

    // connect to pipes created by server
f1=CreateFile(TEXT("\\\\.\\PIPE\\fifo1"), GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
f2=CreateFile(TEXT("\\\\.\\PIPE\\fifo2"), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

while(n<=9){
    for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){
        printf("[%s]",&l1[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){
        printf("[%s]",&l2[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){
        printf("[%s]",&l3[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    x=0;
    Sleep(3000);
    if (ReadFile(f2, lineChar, sizeof(lineChar), &x, NULL)==0) {
                printf("reading error..%d\n", x);
            }
    printf("%s",lineChar);
    //lineInt=atoi(lineChar);
    //printf("\n%d\n",lineInt);
    n++;
}
CloseHandle(f1);
CloseHandle(f2);
}
```

Comment: why do you attempt to display data before you received anything? makes no sense.

Comment: X&O? Do you mean Noughts and Crossed / Tic Tac Toe?

Answer (score 1):

You have lots or problems with strings and pointers in your code.

To start with you print out the single characters in the arrays as *strings*, which will cause weird output.

Secondly, and *one* of the causes of your problem, when you call `WriteFile` you use `sizeof(lineChar)` which returns the size of *the pointer*, not the length of the string. Use `strlen` instead.

The second cause of your problem is that you cast an integer to a string. *This will not work!* What the statement

```
lineChar=reinterpret_cast<char*>(lineInt);
```

does is that it makes a pointer out of the value in `lineInt`. *This is not a valid pointer!* There are a couple of ways to do it:

1. Use the new [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to convert a value to a `std::string`.
2. Since you mix C and C++ anyway, you could use [`sprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) too.

Your programs have a lot of what is called *undefined behavior*, and you should be happy that neither of them crashes outright.

Comment: i fixed the write problem like you said and did int to string linke this but still it doesn't print nothing.

Comment: sprintf(&lineChar,"   Character: %c\n",lineInt);
    printf("%c \n",lineChar);

Comment: i declared char lineChar; i don't get writing error in pipe but when i print lineChar it prints just a space...

Comment: @user1804610 I recommend you step back, and start over with some string and pointer tutorials, and learn the difference between a string and an array of `char`, and the difference between arrays and pointers.

Comment: i made the program with out ipc.and when i print the game layout and put a x or 0 sthe strings go wild.pls can you tell me how to declare them and how to initiate them i'm gonna put the code below

Comment: @user1804610 Start by changing all `printf("[%s]",&l2[i]);` etc. to `printf("[%c]",l2[i]);`

Comment: i did it and now the char's are filled with simbols.i tried to set the array to null after i declared it like this char l1[3];l1[0]='\0';and it's not working

Comment: ok made it:Dthx for the help.i studied a bit about strings like you said.thx.now i have another problem,when i try to make the int to string.i tried like you said with sprintf

Comment: sprintf(lineChar,"%c",lineInt);

Comment: @user1804610 You should read more about `printf` and it's formatting codes as well. `%c` is for _characters_. If you want integers use e.g. `%d`. Also, `lineChar` can't be a pointer like you have in your source, you have to make it an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
char l1[3]="\0";
char l2[3]="\0";
char l3[3]="\0";
char x='x';
char o='0';
int n=1,lineInt=0,coor=0,next=1;
printf("X & 0 Game :  \n");
while(n<=3){
    for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){
        printf("[%s]",&l1[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){
        printf("[%s]",&l2[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){
        printf("[%s]",&l3[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    switch (next){
        case 1 :{
            printf("To select the line enter 1,2 or 3 : \n");
            scanf_s("%d",&lineInt);
            switch (lineInt){
                case 1 :{
                    printf("Enter the coordinates : \n");
                    scanf_s("%d",&coor);
                    //printf("%c",x);
                    //printf("%d",coor);
                    //strcpy_s(&l1[coor],1,"x");
                    l1[coor]=x;
                    break;
                }
                case 2 :{
                    printf("Enter the coordinates : \n");
                    scanf_s("%d",&coor);
                    l2[coor]=x;
                    break;
                }
                case 3 :{
                    printf("Enter the coordinates : \n");
                    scanf_s("%d",&coor);
                    l2[coor]=x;
                    break;
                }
        next=2;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){
            printf("[%s]",&l1[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){
            printf("[%s]",&l2[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){
            printf("[%s]",&l3[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        case 2 :{
            printf("To select the line enter 1,2 or 3 : \n");
            scanf_s("%d",&lineInt);
            switch (lineInt){
                case 1 :{
                    printf("Enter the coordinates : \n");
                    scanf_s("%d",&coor);
                    l1[coor]=o;
                    break;
                }
                case 2 :{
                    printf("Enter the coordinates : \n");
                    scanf_s("%d",&coor);
                    l2[coor]=o;
                    break;
                }
                case 3 :{
                    printf("Enter the coordinates : \n");
                    scanf_s("%d",&coor);
                    l2[coor]=o;
                    break;
                }
        next=2;
        }
    }
}
n++;
}
}
```

}